# How do I essentially split a boolean function in one string in python?

Tags: python, boolean

I have a string called `hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]`. I only want `["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH"]` to return `True` and the rest of the string to return `False`. How would I do that?

I've currently written this

```
import re
def checkCard():
     hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]
     stack = map(bool, hand)
     print(list(stack))  
checkCard()
```

Comment: `hand` is  not a string it's a list of strings and what do you mean by return your function doesn't return anything you are just printing

Comment: Oh sorry ahha this is my first year doing python, so my wording's all over the place. I'm required to use the map function tool to map my checkCard function onto the list. From there, I turn it into a list and display it. From this, I'm supposed to see a list of True and False values. Unrelated, I then to write a loop to display the card value and the corresponding True or False value at the same position as the card string in the list.

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: output should look something like this: `"KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2" "True", "True","True","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
def checkCard():
    hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]
    true_vals = set(["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH"])
    stack  = map(lambda val: val in true_vals, hand)
    print(*hand)
    print(*stack)
checkCard()
```

Output

```
KC 9D 10S jH 11H 0S HC Q2S 100D 1C 2D2
True True True True False False False False False False False
```

The map function will check each value in hand if it's in a set of true_vals the conversion to set is for performance issues since searching in a set is faster then in a list. 
Then printing the hand and stack by unpacking them in a print statement.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
# import re
def checkCard():
    hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]
    true_vals = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH"]
    bool_op = list(map(lambda val: True if val in true_vals else False, hand))

    print(bool_op)  
checkCard()
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: I have to keep the map function in there to meet the requirements of my practical, so how would i keep it in there?

Comment: Updated to use map function

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `map` function like so:

```py
def checkCard():
     hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]
     stack = map(lambda x: x in ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH"], hand)
     print(list(stack))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, `map(func, iterable)`

```
>>> hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]
>>> 
>>> true_vals = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH"] 
>>> 
>>> list(map(lambda x : True if x in true_vals else False, hand))

[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` and `lambda` and vonversion to `list` is not even needed at all to achieve what you want. The most pythonic and also easiest/simplest solution is making an `in` check in a list comprehension:

```
def checkCard():
    hand = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH","11H", "0S", "HC", "Q2S", "100D", "1C", "2D2"]
    true_values = ["KC", "9D", "10S", "jH"]
    stack = [v in true_values for v in hand]  # check for inclusion in a list comprehension
    print(stack)  
checkCard()
```